# is it return list tile only in firebase animated list

Tags: flutter

when i run with stream builder contains datacolumns and datarows which contains datacells,then it shows a blank page

code shown below

```
class DataItem {
  final String personName;
  final String bookName;
  final String authorName;
  final String date;
  final String time;
  final String submitDate;

  DataItem({
    required this.personName,
    required this.bookName,
    required this.authorName,
    required this.date,
    required this.time,
    required this.submitDate,
  });
}


class RegistrationListDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RegistrationListDemoState createState() => _RegistrationListDemoState();
}

class _RegistrationListDemoState extends State<RegistrationListDemo> {
  final ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref('user').child('bookregistration');
  List<DataItem> dataList = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Registration List'),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Expanded(
          child: FirebaseAnimatedList(
            query: ref,
            itemBuilder: (context, snapshot, animation, index) {

              Map regisrationlist = snapshot.value as Map;
              return ListView(
              children: <Widget>[
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    // Add a new data item
                    setState(() {
                      dataList.add(DataItem(
                        personName: 'john',
                        bookName: 'flutter beginners',
                        authorName: 'williamson',
                        date: '2024-02-06',
                        time: '10:00 AM',
                        submitDate: DateTime.now().toString(),
                      ));
                    });
                  },
                  child: Text('Add Data Item'),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 20),
                // Display data items in a table
                DataTable(
                  columns: [
                    DataColumn(label: Text('Person Name')),
                    DataColumn(label: Text('Book Name')),
                    DataColumn(label: Text('Author Name')),
                    DataColumn(label: Text('Date')),
                    DataColumn(label: Text('Time')),
                    DataColumn(label: Text('Submit Date')),
                    DataColumn(label: Text('Actions')),
                  ],
                  rows: dataList.map((data) {
                    return DataRow(cells: [
                      DataCell(Text(data.personName)),
                      DataCell(Text(data.bookName)),
                      DataCell(Text(data.authorName)),
                      DataCell(Text(data.date)),
                      DataCell(Text(data.time)),
                      DataCell(Text(data.submitDate)),
                      DataCell(
                        IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
                          onPressed: () {
                            // Remove data item
                            setState(() {
                              dataList.remove(data);
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ]);
                  }).toList(),
                ),
              ],
            );   
            }
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

my question is can return any thing to fecth data from real time database like grid view,the return of list tile is very perfect,but in case of others didnt work

I'm using a firebaseAnimatedList to load a data set. I'm trying to create empty states for the app to provide the user some guidance when there is nothing to show. I see there is a defaultChild, but that is only shown until the query returns. If the query returns empty, the defaultChild is removed and an empty page is displayed.